# Add configuration or settings screen in app without using external library

Tags: ios, objective-c, appsettings

I have searched on web but unable to find a simple way to add configuration or settings screen in my app. I have found many solutions which asks to add a library named InAppSettingsKit. But I dont want to use any external library for that. As I have already used many libraries in my app.

How I can achieve it? I know if I use `settings.bundle`, I can have settings page in iPhone settings. But I want to have it in my app.

Comment: Have you considered manually saving to a `plist` file and modifying that?

Comment: why don't create your own UIViewController and customise it the way you want...